# Finding $\phi'(0)$ of $\phi(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(\frac{1}{t})dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find $\phi'(0)$ of $\phi(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(\frac{1}{t})dt$, $\phi:[0,\infty] \to \mathbb{R}, $but don't really have any idea on how to find that since the function is undefined at that point. The limit also doesn't exist there so we cannot redefine the function...

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: the integral diverges at the lower limit $0.$

Comment: @abel Why do you say that?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, $\phi'(0)=0.$ Let $t=1/s$ to see

$$\int_0^x \sin (1/t)\,dt = \int_{1/x}^\infty (\sin s)/s^2 ds.$$

Integrate by parts to see the last integral equals

$$(1) \,\,\,\,x^2\cos (1/x) -2\int_{1/x}^\infty (\cos s)/s^3 \, ds.$$

The absolute value of the last integral is $\le \int_{1/x}^\infty 1/s^3 \, ds = x^2/2.$ If we now multiply (1) by $1/x,$ we get an expression that is $O(x) \to 0.$

Comment: I could not understand your last line one...Can you help me ???